# Using wtforms Fieldlist with a Selectedfield does not return data

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms, wtforms

i'm trying to use a list of SelectField from wtforms and generate them dynamically using FieldList. My simplified forms look like this:

```py
class SingleForm(FlaskForm):
    option = SelectField(coerce=str)

class SetForm(FlaskForm):
    options = FieldList(FormField(SingleForm))
```

And I initialised the label and choices for each SelectField this way:

```py
    set_form = SetForm()
    idx = 0
    for k, v in dic_options.items():
        set_form.options.append_entry(SingleForm())

        set_form.options[idx].option.name = 'option' + str(idx)
        set_form.options[idx].option.label = str(k)
        set_form.options[idx].option.choices = [''] + list(map(str, v))

        idx += 1
```

This displays the options and values correctly but my issue is when I submit the form I am not able to retrieve the data using the `set_form` object because `set_form.options` is empty. If I look at `request.form` I can actually see the values that were entered for each SelectField, so what would you say is missing / wrong in my code to be able to access these data via the `set_form` object?

Comment: there are logical issue in wtforms FieldList when work with selectfield, if the user not selected value wtforms will not return anything or entry represet that there was input here. no form.fild.entries, and no form.fild.data , if user enter value it suddenly remeber that there was input and return value to it (this must solved in next update) as known in select HTML you can only have  1 value for id or for other item, if you need id and some data for that id you need two fieldList and if you have to lists and decided access with index you must have equal lists that's why I say there are error

Answer (score 0):

You need to populate the choices again where you're processing the form.